# Running a Batch File (.bat) as Administrator from the Current Directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, administrator

I am currently writing a code for a School allowing students to simply run a Batch File as Administrator on their windows device and receive the required programs for using the networks infrastructure.

```
@echo Welcome to the Mossman State High School Additional Features Installer
@pause

@echo Starting the Credentials GUI
@echo Starting PaperCut Installer
@start "" %~dp0BYOx.exe
@start "" %~dp0client-local-install.exe

@echo Creating Printing Directory
@md C:\Printing

@echo Copying Print Mapping Files
@copy "" %~dp0configuration.xml C:\Printing /E /W
@copy "" %~dp0student_printers.xml C:\Printing /E /W
@copy "" %~dp0PrintMap2.exe C:\Printing /E /W

@copy "" %~dp0StudentPrinting.sfx.exe C:\ /E /W

@echo Running Connect Printer Setup
@start "C:\" StudentPrinting.sfx.exe

@echo Please complete the instructions on BYOx and PaperCut to finilize 
onboarding.
@pause
```

Due to the way the StudentPrinting.sfx.exe program was previously written and as it needs to be run from the C:\ Directory, it needs to be run as administrator.

I had originally found that the `%~dp0` parameter worked but once further testing occurred, i discovered it fails once hitting a Computer Name with a Space in it eg. `C:\Users\ComputerOne\Desktop\Auto_Installer` works but `C:\Users\Computer One\Desktop\Auto_Installer` doesn't due to the space between Computer and One. As it will be used by students aged from 12 to 18, they would not be able to fix this.

Is there a way to have a Batch File run as administrator but still run from the directory it lives in?

Comment: If you don't mind the question: Why use `@command` in every single line instead of `@echo off` in the beginning?

Comment: Please look up the correct syntax of the [`START`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) and [`COPY`](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) commands. You will also find that browsing through [SS64's CMD.EXE reference](http://ss64.com/nt/) will be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would ensure first that your current directory matches that of the script. *(That way there'll be no need to prefix with %~dp0)*. There also seems to be not good reason why you need to use `Start` and your `Copy` commands appear to be using the wrong syntax with incorrect options.

```bat
@Echo Off

If /I Not "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" CD /D "%~dp0"

Echo Welcome to the Mossman State High School Additional Features Installer
Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul

Echo Copying Print Mapping Files
If Not Exist C:\Printing\ (
    Echo Creating Printing Directory
    MD C:\Printing
)
Copy /Y configuration.xml C:\Printing
Copy /Y student_printers.xml C:\Printing
Copy /Y PrintMap2.exe C:\Printing

Echo Copying printer Setup Files
Copy /Y StudentPrinting.sfx.exe C:\

Echo Running Connect Printer Setup
C:\StudentPrinting.sfx.exe

Echo Please complete the instructions on BYOx and PaperCut to finilize onboarding.

Echo Starting the Credentials GUI
BYOx.exe

Echo Starting PaperCut Installer
client-local-install.exe

Echo(
Echo Finished. Press any key to exit...
Timeout -1
```

I have changed the order around to that which appears to make more sense, *if the printer setup cannot be run before the other two executables have been run then please adjust accordingly.*

Comment: Why not simply using `cd /D "%~dp0."` (no `if`)?

Comment: You may argue that there would be no difference with regards the end product or that there will be no error shown; however I think it's better practice. *(I don't want to paint my walls white if they are already painted white)*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from what i understand this is the right solution: 
First block of code checks for admin and prompts you to accept if you are not , or if you are already, it runs the commands AS ADMIN.
Then PUSHD %~dp0 makes sure you are working in the current directory the .bat is at (C:\ in your case)
Then you can use just the program name if it's in the same directory as the .bat file! (no need to specify path)

Save this as .bat and try to adapt it with your code as needed (watch for the line i specified you put your code after):

```
@echo off&cls
REM  --> CHECKING FOR ADMIN
    IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
REM -----------------PUT YOUR COMMANDS BELOW THIS LINE-------------------
CLS
PUSHD %~dp0
echo %CD%
echo.
echo HELLO!
echo.
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Compo & Raphael for assisting with the programming. I have tested the program on a virtual machine and it works as expected.

The finished code is as follows;

```
@echo off&cls
    IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" 
"%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" 
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > 
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 
>> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"

If /I Not "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" CD /D "%~dp0"

echo Welcome to the Mossman State High School Additional Features Installer
timeout 1 /NoBreak>Nul

echo Copying Print Mapping Files
if not exist C:\Printing\ (
    echo Creating Printing Directory
    md C:\Printing
)
copy /Y configuration.xml C:\Printing
copy /Y student_printers.xml C:\Printing
copy /Y PrintMap2.exe C:\Printing

echo Copying Printer Setup Files
copy /Y StudentPrinting.sfx.exe C:\

echo Running Connect Printer Setup
C:\StudentPrinting.sfx.exe

echo Please complete the instructions on BYOx and PaperCut to finilize 
onboarding.

echo Starting the Credentials GUI
start BYOx.exe

echo Starting PaperCut Installer
start client-local-install.exe

echo(
echo Finished. Press any key to exit...
timeout -1
```